# Table rowspan issue

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have the following table. The header is at it looks and the content is generated within a PHP loop. It contains some taxes that a user has to pay and a tax can be paid in installments. For example, if the user has to pay a 100$ tax and he first pays 25$ and then 75$, there will be two rows in the table for that tax.

What I seem to fail to accomplish is to make a rowspan so the tax name will be displayed only once.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>                                                        
            <th width="10%">Tax name</th>
            <th width="10%">Value</th>
            <th width="10%">Paid</th>
            <th width="10%">Rest</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>                                    
            <td>Sign-up tax</td>
            <td>100$</td>
            <td>25$</td>
            <td>75$</td>                        
        </tr>   
        <tr>                                    
            <td>Sign-up tax</td>
            <td>100$</td>
            <td>75$</td>
            <td>0$</td>                        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax_details); $i++): ?>
<tr>                                    
    <td><?php echo $tax_details[$i]['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details[$i]['value']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details[$i]['paid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details[$i]['rest']; ?></td>                        
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the table? Would be easier to provide an answer that is more easily understood by you.

Comment: I have updated the post Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the html with this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>                                    
        <td rowspan="2">Sign-up tax</td>   <---add rowspan here
        <td>100$</td>
        <td>25$</td>
        <td>75$</td>                        
    </tr>   
    <tr>                                    
        <td>100$</td>         <---remove second sign-up tax from here
        <td>75$</td>
        <td>0$</td>                        
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I want to generate it with PHP.

Comment: Then you'd need to examine your data set first and figure out which rows will need spanning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, I don't see the problem.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>                                                        
            <th width="10%">Tax name</th>
            <th width="10%">Value</th>
            <th width="10%">Paid</th>
            <th width="10%">Rest</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tax_details); $i++): ?>
<tr>                                    
    <td><?php echo $tax_details['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details['value']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details['paid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tax_details['rest']; ?></td>                        
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I fail to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I need to do a rowspan for the first column.